# tikzpicture cannot draw in subfigure/subcaption/subfloat

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, subcaption, subfig

I tried to place two tikzpictures in one figure as two subfigures, but the tikzpicture did not draw properly in subfigure.
I have tried package subfig, subfigure, subcaption, they all failed.

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as line]
data [headline={x, y}] {
    0, 0
    1, 1
    2, 1
    3, 0
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
\subfloat[Case I]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as line]
    data [headline={x, y}] {
        0, 0
        1, 1
        2, 1
        3, 0
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\label{fig_first_case}}
\hfil
\subfloat[Case II]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as line]
    data [headline={x, y}] {
        0, 0
        1, 1
        2, 1
        3, 0
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\label{fig_second_case}}
\caption{Simulation results for the network.}
\label{fig_sim}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

And the output is as follow:
[image]

Comment: For me the `subcaption` package and its `subfigure` environment works just fine. Could you please show how you tried using this package?

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for your replay. I used \subcaptionbox and failed. I tried subfigure of subcaption package as you suggested and it works just fine.

Comment: You get the same problem if you use \sbox0{...}, but not using \setbox0=\hbox{,,,} which is supposed to be identical.  I think someone has been messing around with the LaTeX kernel, and I hope like heck they aren't using expl3!

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate my comment:

Of course, it only seems to affect tikzpicture, not subfloat (which uses saveboxes to measure the width).  Nor does redefining \sbox and \savebox help.

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}
\sbox0{\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as line]
data [headline={x, y}] {
    0, 0
    1, 1
    2, 1
    3, 0
};
\end{tikzpicture}}\usebox0% does not work right

\setbox0=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as line]
data [headline={x, y}] {
    0, 0
    1, 1
    2, 1
    3, 0
};
\end{tikzpicture}}\usebox0

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\subfloat[Case I]{\usebox0
\label{fig_first_case}}
\hfil
\subfloat[Case II]{\usebox0
\label{fig_second_case}}
\caption{Simulation results for the network.}
\label{fig_sim}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```